# Multisort by distance

Tags: php, usort

I have a multidimensional array and want to sort it by distance:

```
[clustermarkers] => [
            0 => [
                    0 => [
                      'name' => 'A',
                      'distance' => 10
                    ]
            ],
            1 => [
                    0 => [
                      'name' => 'B',
                      'distance' => 8
                    ]
            ],
            ...
];
```

I have tried usort function, but something wrong:

```
usort($clustermarkers, function($a, $b) {
   return (int)$a['distance'] - (int)$b['distance'];
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `usort` function, just add `[0]` to `$a` and `$b` before `['distance']`

```
usort($clustermarkers, function ($a, $b) {
    return $a[0]['distance'] - $b[0]['distance'];
});

print_r($clustermarkers);
```

Answer (score 0):

Almost:

```
usort($clustermarkers, function($a, $b) {
   return $a['distance'] > $b['distance']; //Distance ASC
});

usort($clustermarkers, function($a, $b) {
   return $a['distance'] < $b['distance']; //Distance DESC
});
```

note the `<` and `>` operators and not casting to `int`

Comment: Notice: Undefined index: distance